# How to execute plain Redis queries in Java

Tags: java, redis, lettuce, redisson

I need to make native queries to Redis in the Java code.
Is there a Java library or another way to do this?

I need something like this:

```
someRedisClient.execute("FT.SEARCH SOME_INDEX (@foo:bar*)")
```

I didn't find such feature in lettuce, lettusearch, redisson.

Comment: Did you check JRediSearch? https://github.com/RediSearch/JRediSearch

Comment: `FT.SEARCH` is not a native Redis query. So, what do you mean by "native" query?

Comment: @GuyKorland No, I'll check it, thanks

Comment: @sazzad Yes, I know that, I mean the feature to execute a query to Redis as a string, just like in redis-cli, but in java code, something like this: `someRedisClient.execute("FT.SEARCH SOME_INDEX (@foo:bar*)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jedis](https://github.com/redis/jedis) has `sendCommand` methods which supports what you want but with a caveat. The method signatures are as follows:

```
Object sendCommand(ProtocolCommand cmd, byte[]... args)
Object sendCommand(ProtocolCommand cmd, String... args)
```

As you can see, you must have an implementation of ProtocolCommand representing the actual command. It is commonly done by `enum`.

```
public enum Command implements ProtocolCommand {
  
  FT_SEARCH("FT.SEARCH");
  
  private final byte[] raw;
  
  private Command(String str) {
    raw = str.getBytes();
  }
  
  @Override
  public byte[] getRaw() {
    return raw;
  }
}
```

After that,

```
jedis.sendCommand(Command.FT_SEARCH, "SOME_INDEX", "(@foo:bar*)");
```

Yes, the command arguments are separate strings, instead of concatenated by space.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this)